# React Native, Managed Expo app using IOS simulator gives Network Error calling API endpoint

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am developing a react native managed expo app on MacOS and using IOS simulator (IPhone 14 Plus)

I am getting a "Network Error" when calling an api endpoint, which was working previously. Proxyman shows a request as Internal Error, code 999.

1. I can access my local IP from the simulator browser.
2. I can access the api endpoint from the simulator browser as well.
3. But cannot access the endpoint from the expo app.
4. I tried another simulator, same problem.
5. I can reach the endpoint from Postman too.

Im running
MacOS Monterey
RN 0.71.8
Expo 48
Simulator IOS 16.2

I cant think of anything else to try to debug it?

Any ideas appreciated?

Malcolm

Comment: What does your info.plist looks like? Can you include it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was I had not reinstalled the proxyman certificate for IOS simulator after I had reset all proxyman certificates due to an expired root certificate.